# Do you have to use Xbox Live to save/track progress?

Tags: zumba-fitness-rush

I have an Xbox in my living room, but all my computer devices are across the house.  I don't have a wireless connection and can not get a physical cable long enough to reach Xbox.  Is it possible to use the track progress feature on my new Zumba Rush game while offline?

Comment: Normally, game progress is saved on a local device (ie, an internal hard drive or something similar) as opposed to being saved on Xbox LIVE.  I can't confirm with this particular game, but I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Any progress (if the progress system is similar to the Your Shape: FE games) should be cached locally and synced to Live when the connection is available.